# French translation for "let's cross that bridge when we come to it"? — Comment traduire « let's cross that bridge when we come to it » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

In English, the expression "let's cross than bridge when we come to it" exists, to indicate that the speaker doesn't want to deal with a particular outcome because, as that outcome may not happen, it could be a waste of time.  For example,

> "What happens if our car breaks down on the way to the shops?"
>   "Let's cross that bridge when we come to it."

What's the best way to express the sentiment of this expression in French?

---

L'expression anglaise « let's cross that bridge when we come to it » signifie que l'on ne souhaite pas s'occuper d'une situation potentiellement problématique maintenant, car, étant donné que le problème peut éventuellement ne jamais se présenter, il s'agirait d'une perte de temps. Par exemple,

> — Qu'arrivera-t-il si notre voiture tombe en panne en allant faire les courses ?
>   — *Let's cross that bridge when we come to it.*

Quelle est la meilleure façon de rendre le sens de cette expression en français ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In French we would say (non exhaustive list):

- Formal version:

  > — Que ferons nous si notre voiture tombe en panne en allant faire les courses ?
  >   — Inutile de répondre à une question qui ne s'est pas encore posée.

  This is not an expression as such, but a quite common wording to express the feeling you have described.
- Normal version:

  > — Que ferons nous si notre voiture tombe en panne en allant faire les courses ?
  >   — Nous verrons bien si cela se produit.

  This is almost an expression, and it also corresponds well.
- Familiar version:

  > — Que ferons nous si notre voiture tombe en panne en allant faire les courses ?
  >   — Ne tire pas de plans sur la comète.

  This one is an expression and it says exactly what you have described in your question.

Comment: +1, mais pour moi les plans sur la comète, c'est, comme la peau de l'ours ou la charrue et les bœufs, utilisé pour réduire un enthousiasme excessif trop pressé à passer à l'étape suivante, pas pour dire qu'il est inutile de s'occuper d'un problème trop incertain.

Comment: Ah, tu penses ? Je l'entends (et l'emploie d'ailleurs) souvent pour les deux choses.

Comment: http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/tirer-des-plans-sur-la-comete.php semble d'accord avec moi, ce qui ne veut pas dire que ce n'est pas utilisé autrement aussi.

Comment: Un « plan sur la comète » a quelque chose d'entousiasmant («  faire des projets audacieux ; faire des projets chimériques »), ce n'est pas le cas d'une panne de voiture... (sauf situation de drague !). À mon avis ça ne va pas du tout avec le contexte. On dirais plutôt « te casse pas la tête, on verra bien ».

Answer (score 38):

One could use

> *Chaque chose en son temps*
>   Everything [is to be done] in its own time

or

> *Une chose à la fois*
>   One thing at a time

Comment: Je ne sais pas quel est le niveau de vocabulaire de "Let's cross that bridge when we come to it.", mais "chaque chose en son temps" est pour moi la phrase que j'utiliserais le plus naturellement.

Comment: Ou aussi : "on verra en temps et en heure."

Comment: Pas vraiment d'accord, les deux expressions proposées ne font pas ressortir le fait que la voiture pourrait très bien ne pas tomber en panne. Elles sont utilisées quand l'avenir n'est pas teinté d'incertitude comme c'est le cas en anglais.

Answer (score 15):

In Quebec we use the direct translation

"on traversera le pont lorsqu'on arrivera à la rivière"

Comment: Oui mais vous autres vous parlez comme 'Google translate' ;-)

Comment: @boisvert C'est toujours mieux que parking, shopping, fioule et compagnie. Aussi, c'est la seule réponse valable selon moi. "Ne tire pas de plans sur la comète" is the most upvoted answer. Seriously ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Comme on dit "les francais se garent sur le parking, mais les québecois se parquent sur le stationnement". Google translate, c'etait pour rire, mais si tu es vraiment inquiet, tu sous-estimes la souplesse et la richesse de ta langue. Par exemple (pour ne prendre que des particularités qui frappent un non-spécialiste), l'inversion pronom sujet - verbe (en veux-tu?), devenue desuète en France; les deux 1ères personnes du pluriel ('nous' / 'nous autres'); le nombre d'expressions maritimes entrées dans le langage courant (gréer un café).

Answer (score 13):

Je dirais simplement « On verra bien », assorti le cas échéant d'un complément de temps ou de lieu :

I would simply say "On verra bien", usually with a time or place complement:

> Comment va-t-on faire pour payer le loyer à la fin du mois ? (*How will we pay the rent at the end of the month?*)
>   Je ne sais pas, on verra bien à ce moment-là. (*I don't know, we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.*)

> Si on va chez tes parents, j'espère qu'on ne devra pas joueur au bridge. (*If we go to your parent's, I hope we won't have to play bridge.*)
>   Écoute, on verra ça sur place. (*Listen, we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.* Kinda less funny in French, I guess.)

Comment: Grmmm... j'ai encore répondu en français à une question posée en anglais, sans réfléchir

Comment: Tu n'es pas le seul.

Comment: Et j'ai bien failli le faire...

Comment: "on verra bien" is the first thing that came to my mind too

Comment: I would have said « On verra ça quand on y sera ».

Answer (score 10):

> Nous discuterons de cela en temps et heure.

Selon l'intonation, employé en tant que réponse, ça peut paraître un peu froid, voire glacial.

Comment: Ou « en temps utile », ou encore « le moment venu ».

Comment: Tout à fait, et ça devient ainsi un peu plus cordial.

Comment: Rien de tel qu'un cordial quand il fait glacial, je suppose.

Answer (score 6):

D'après [Guy Bertrand](http://www.radio-canada.ca/radio/francaisaumicro/index.asp?dateachercher=1/31/2011), l'expression "On traversera le pont quand on sera rendu à la rivière…" est amplement utilisé au Québec, mais il serait préférable d'utilisé la tournure équivalente : "**On verra en temps et lieu**"

> La formule on traversera le pont quand on sera rendu à la rivière et ses nombreuses variantes sont des calques approximatifs de l’anglais. Bien que la faute ne soit pas très grave (il n’y a aucune entorse au génie de la langue), il est toujours préférable d’utiliser la tournure équivalente reconnue, en l’occurrence : On verra en temps et lieu (ou en temps utile, en temps voulu, en temps opportun). La locution synonyme on verra en temps et heure (ou en temps et en heure) est pratiquement inusitée chez nous.
>
> Nota : Certains puristes critiquent la locution traverser un pont. Il est vrai qu’en réalité, on traverse le cours d’eau qui coule sous le pont et non le pont lui-même. Toutefois, cet emploi est considéré comme correct en français moderne.

Answer (score 5):

Dans ton exemple, je dirais facilement « Qui vivra verra. », mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit le cas de tous les contextes ni que la nuance soit parfaitement rendue.

« Il ne faut pas aller plus vite que la musique. » doit pouvoir aussi parfois être utilisé.

Answer (score 4):

Dans certains contextes, on peut utiliser:

> À chaque jour suffit sa peine.

ou bien:

> Carpe diem.

Comment: +1 pour "à chaque jour suffit sa peine" (à peu près synonyme à "chaque chose en son temps"). En revanche, "carpe diem" ne veut absolument pas dire la même chose.

Answer (score 3):

— Que ferons nous si notre voiture tombe en panne en allant faire les courses ?
— Le temps venu, on avisera.

Answer (score 2):

Parallèlement à la traduction littérale assez commune au Québec *(On traversera le pont rendus à la rivière*, déjà proposée dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1159/13100)) ou à sa version écourtée (*On traversera le pont une fois rendus*), se rencontre aussi assez souvent  : *« [On verra dans le temps comme dans le temps](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/lexique/definition-expression/canada/dans-le-temps-comme-dans-le-temps/). »*

Par exemple :

> — Et si l'auto nous laissait tomber à mi-chemin ?
> — **On verra ça dans le temps comme dans le temps.**

Answer (score 0):

I have already read the expression "*Ne crions pas avant d'avoir mal*", which literally means "let's not shout in pain before it actually hurts", and conveys the message: no point in complaining or worrying too loudly about some future undesirable occurrence later, let's just wait to see if it actually arises.

Answer (score 0):

La traduction doit prendre en compte à la fois une certaine confiance en la capacité de faire face à une épreuve et le fait qu'il se pourrait bien que l'épreuve ne se présente pas. Elle doit donc s'adresser à une double inquiétude : que des ennuis se produisent et que l'on soit capable d'y faire face. Dans cet esprit je suggère :

- T'inquiète pas, on fera face.
- C'est même pas sûr, et de toute façon on s'en sortira / réussira bien à s'en sortir.